# ESP8266 hadrware timer, uS to ticks strange macro

Tags: c, macros, esp8266

Can someone explain me why this macro is written like this?!?...

Trying to understand how the ESP8266 hardware timer works, since manufacturer doesn't provide much data and their examples are just spagetti code.

Now a timer is a timer, just counts (down to 0 in ESP8266) based on it's HW clock and in this case is APB/4 or 20 MHz.

The uS to TICKS should be as simple as that:

```
ticks = uS * MHz
```

Now the Espressif examples shows a macro which basically do the same as above, depending on magic number 0x35A... ???

The magic path would be equivalent to:

```
ticks = uS/4 (no float, rounded dwn) * MHz * 4
        +
        us%4 * MHz
```

Why is that? Am I missing something?

Original one:

```
#define US_TO_RTC_TIMER_TICKS(t)          \
    ((t) ?                                   \
     (((t) > 0x35A) ?                   \
      (((t)>>2) * ((APB_CLK_FREQ>>4)/250000) + ((t)&0x3) * ((APB_CLK_FREQ>>4)/1000000))  :    \
      (((t) *(APB_CLK_FREQ>>4)) / 1000000)) :    \
     0)
```

Now breaking into it, it turns out that:

```
#define US_TO_RTC_TIMER_TICKS(t)          
    (

    (t) ? ( // if t, ok for now

        // hmmm... magic number for a timer 0x35A or 858 dec  
        ((t) > 0x35A) ?

        ( // if greater than magic number

            ((t)>>2) * ((APB_CLK_FREQ>>4)/250000) + ((t)&0x3) * ((APB_CLK_FREQ>>4)/1000000)

            // t/4[uS] * 80 equivalent with t * 20 but with match round
            // Example
            // 103uS normal would be 103uS * 20 = 2060 (as count)
            //
            // 103/4 = 25 * 80 = 2000 + 3 * 20 = 2000 + 60 = 2060 
            // hmmm.. correct but why?

        )  :    
        (
            // if lower than MAGIC
            // t / period = count <=> t[uS] * freq[MHz] = count
            //
            // t * 20   this is understandable :) 
            // 
            ((t) *(APB_CLK_FREQ>>4)) / 1000000
        )


        ) :   0 



     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply to prevent overflow. If the start value is greater than "not a magic number" then the multiplication with 'clock frequency / 4' can cause an overflow. To prevent this you can divide the number by four first (by bit-shifting so: '>> 2') but that would lose the resolution of the lower two bits because they would be lost. So the lower two bits are separated and then accounted for.

You can get the magic number by dividing the max value of an int by `APB_CLK_FREQ >> 4` i.e.

`(2 ^ 32 - 1) / ((80 * 10 ^ 6) / 16) = 858.99`

We'll round off to a lower value so the max value we can handle directly is 858 or 0x35A.

I'd also like to correct you on the tics front. The hardware timer runs on the CPU frequency and the hw_timer source uses a prescaler of 16 though you can modify the source (with some effort - read the register definitions in the technical manual of esp8266) to use a prescaler of 1 or 256 too apart from 16.

So the tics per us would be

`us * 80 * 10 ^ 6 / <pre-scaler>`

Comment: I just discovered that HW timer gets feed on CPU clock. Regarding macro, still don't understand: if make the division with 1000000 FIRST, nothing can overflow. This is a macro and with UL shall be evaluated by preprocesor first, THEN compiled, isn't it? Thanks!

Comment: If you make a division with 1000000 first, you lose resolution of the lower bytes yet again. Dividing any number with anything will lose the resolution of the lower bites so to get maximum resolution you'd want to do all the multiplication first and then divide. Example: (100 / 7) * 5 = 70 but, (100 * 5) / 7 = 71. Also the preprocessor doesn't compute anything, the compiler computes the values it knows at compile time and it can't mess with the bounds etc of values! - that would be very wrong.. The compiler must compile as if the code was running on the target machine.

Comment: Well. yes and no :) Since APB is fixed in ESP8266 case, either 80000000 or 160000000, division with 1000000 will yield the same result, 8 or 16. Preprocesor shall evaluate all that can be reduced to const, that's why we use parenthesis (). There is absolute no sense to make (APB/1000000) at compile time since this can be evaluated at design time. But anyhow, thanks again! I accepted because technically, you are right.